# In case of confusion and controversies, is there an Islamic authority that has a ruling to address the issue?

Tags: ijma

New and complicated problems arise every now and then. They are almost bound with the time. In case an issue arises, Is there any Muslim body/school who can resolve the issue, by offering their own ruling? How well their ruling is accepted across different countries and among Muslims?

I would like to know Sunni School of thought as well Shia schools of thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no one body that is accepted by Muslims anywhere (and this could be more of a blessing than a hindrance). There has been a trend over the past half-century or so to form councils that issue fatawa in response to issues that come up. These councils accept pertinent questions, discuss it among themselves, and finally issue their ruling. Some are well-accepted across the Muslim world and some limited to their geographic region. For the most part, they are by country. Some examples include:

> Islamic Fiqh Council of the Muslim World League
>
> Dar al-Ifta al-Masriyyah
>
> Ifta at any Darul Uloom in India, Pakistan, South Africa, England, etc.
>
> Fiqh Council of North America
>
> Assembly of Muslim Jurists of America
>
> European Council for Fatwa and Research
>
> Lajnah Da'imah (Saudi Arabia)

and many more. The fiqh councils of Azhar, Arabia, and Darul Uloom have large followings all over the world. The others are mainly restricted to their respective regions.

Comment: It would be nice to have links to them if available, although it is not a request :)